# Ruby (on Rails + Heroku) framework for interaction with custom data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

Is there any recommended (by you) CMS/CMF for Ruby, that allows simple interaction with custom data? Have you got any recommended approaches? The data won't be too much complicated. Heroku compliance is a must.

One other thing. It came out, that I have got little time to provide a demo. Are the proposed frameworks real time-savers, including time required to learn the framework?

Comment: I will choose the answer as soon as I have time to check them out. For now, I stick with pure Rails, without any 3rd party framework.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As no answer was submitted after update - just take your time, learn RoR well and write the code you need. Ultimately, I used no external framework.

Answer (score 0):

If I am understanding your question correctly, I would recommend [RailsAdmin](https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin/)or [Jeweli](http://www.jewelicms.com/about). There is an extensive list [here](http://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/crm_apps.html)

Answer (score 0):

Will [Locomotive CMS](http://www.locomotivecms.com/) cut it for you? It has [custom content types](http://www.locomotivecms.com/features) and fields. And it [works with Heroku](http://www.locomotivecms.com/support/installation/heroku). Since it is a fully fledged Rails engine, you can just set it up and have it running within minutes.